# PHP Session expires randomly

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I red a lot about Sessions but up to now I cannot explain, why users report that the sessions of the software sometimes expires after few Minutes, sometimes after 1.5 hours. Ideally, I want the session to expire after a 12 hours. I tried a tons of settings after reading even more tons of things about sessions. I absolutely have no idea what I can do.
As a background, I a using CakePHP 2.8. In future we will change CakePHP but another framework, but this will take its time and we have to fix the Session problem before.

The web server is running on an apache and ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: I think it is about callling session_destroy method in somepage. So when user opens the page his/her session is destroyed. Or maybe it is about [php garbage collector](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-gc.php).

Comment: I watched at the session_destroy. That is only called at the log out function. Therefore I think that the session is not destroyed. The garbage collector is new for me. Is it somehow possible to say that the collector should run once a day? As I understand the text right it just runs as soon as it get full. Therefore I cannot really handle when someone is logged out?!
As I see on the picture the gc_lifetime is at 12 hours. But this do not fit.

Comment: I have another idea. On a server, there are several "same" systems that are used for different issues. All of the store the session at "session.save_path /var/lib/php/sessions". Might this cause a problem?

Comment: Did you check session timeout in cakephp configuration?

Comment: I checked the configuration. Finally I fixed my problem. I changed the session settings from php to database in the core.php. Now the sessions are handled by the database and they do not expire randomly. My suspicion is, that the php session was deleted by the garbage collector also by other applications that are running on the server and therefore randomly destroyed the sessions.